# HttpDeleteAttribute decorator, valid template? C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

Is the next template route valid?

```
[HttpDelete("withdrawal/client/{clientId}/dni/{dni}?catalogNumber={catalogNumber}&warehouse={warehouseId}")]
```

I receive an exception, with the next description:

```yaml
RoutePatternException: The literal section '?catalogNumber=' is invalid. Literal sections cannot contain the '?' character.
```

Any help would be nice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of including the query params in the string literal you can specify them in the function declaration

```
[HttpDelete("withdrawal/client/{clientId}/dni/{dni}")]
public void Foo([FromQuery] string catalogNumber, [FromQuery] string warehouseId)
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank's, works very well

Answer (score 0):

for url

```
http://.../withdrawal/client/{clientId}/dni/{dni}?catalogNumber={catalogNumber}&warehouse={warehouseId}
```

your action should be

```
[HttpDelete("withdrawal/client/{clientId}/dni/{dni}")]
public IActionResult client(int client, string dni, string catalogNumber, string warehouse)
{
  ...
}
```

or you can make this url

```
http://../withdrawal/client/{clientId}/dni/{dni}/{catalogNumber?}/{warehouseId?}")]
```

your action should be

`````
[HttpDelete("withdrawal/client/{clientId}/dni/{dni}/{catalogNumber?}/{warehouseId?}")]
public IActionResult client(int client, string dni, string catalogNumber, string warehouse)
{
  ...
}
````
`````